# Как сделать чтобы в браузер показывал не номер строки скомпилированного css, а номер препроцессорной строки

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, gulp, scss

[image: Вот пример]

У меня autoprefixer показывает ошибку и номер символа в строке, никак не могу перейти к нему, но помню что gulp может такой фокус но я не помню как это делается. Буду очень благодарен если поможете. Спасибо!

Comment: Нужно включить создание map файла, не знаю как это там делается, думаю сможете найти.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к ответу выше. Меняйте настройки галпа или вебпака

Comment: Спасибо!! разобрался